# Prior to the CW tv series, has Felicity Smoak had any interaction with the Green Arrow?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow, green-arrow

In the CW tv series Felicity Smoak is one of the core members of Team Arrow and a potential love interest (though it's become quite the mess because of Plot Drama). But from what I can gather she has her origins in the Firestorm series, another DC superhero.

So I am wondering, has there ever been any interaction between Felicity Smoak and the Green Arrow, in or out of his costume, prior to her becoming part of the Arrow's team in the TV series?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there was no interaction between Green Arrow and Felicity in the DC universe, prior to *Arrow*. Felicity's character only ever appeared in *Firestorm* titles, and she's a significantly different character in the comics (and eventually, Firestorm's mother in law.)

Note that, after the New 52 reboot, Felicity did not reappear in the DC universe until 2014, where she is now effectively a copy of her character on *Arrow*. This character has only ever appeared in *Green Arrow* issues, and not reappeared in the rebooted *Firestorm* story.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that she appeared in the New 52 reboot. But has she appeared in her "home" series of Firestorm since the reboot?

Comment: Nope; added to the answer.